# Is there a way to only assign a class to something if its on a mobile device

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navigation

I have just finished styling a menu, but I want it to all merge into a mobile style menu on a mobile device. The site is [here](http://legalstudiesacademy.com/test/).

Here is the HTML for the menu:

```html
          <div class="masthead clearfix">
            <div class="inner">
              <h3 class="masthead-brand">ONLY AT LSA</h3>
              <nav>
                <ul class="nav masthead-nav">
                  <li class="active"><a href="#">The Experience</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Recent News</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
                </ul>
              </nav>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Here is the CSS for the menu:

```css
.masthead-brand {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.masthead-nav > li {
  display: inline-block;
}
.masthead-nav > li + li {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
.masthead-nav > li > a {
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff; /* IE8 proofing */
  color: rgba(255,255,255,.75);
  border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
}
.masthead-nav > li > a:hover,
.masthead-nav > li > a:focus {
  background-color: transparent;
  border-bottom-color: #a9a9a9;
  border-bottom-color: rgba(255,255,255,.25);
}
.masthead-nav > .active > a,
.masthead-nav > .active > a:hover,
.masthead-nav > .active > a:focus {
  color: #fff;
  border-bottom-color: #fff;
}
```

So I want it to go from [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNeXv.png) to your ideal mobile navigation system with the icon that you click and it expands the menu.

Comment: If you implement a good browser-platform detection script then you can create an `if-then` condition to correct render the contents according to user device.

Comment: I don't understand your question, but maybe you just want a hamburger menu? Check the demo and code at [this link](http://kmturley.blogspot.ru/2014/06/responsive-mobile-dropdown-navigation.html)

Comment: Looks pretty good, but I say ditch the animation on the modal (gonna be laggy on mobile). As for the nav, just have a separate version of the nav already in the markup with a class of `.fly-out-nav` and an icon with a class of `.menu-trigger` and only show them on mobile using your media queries. Look here for an example: https://www.spanishwizards.com/

Comment: Just add an additional class to your `class` attribute. Then add the additional class to css using media queries

Comment: media queries are your friends!

Answer (score 0):

You should use CSS

```
/* All Mobile Sizes */
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) { ... }
```

Comment: The OP should use CSS! Why did I not think of that! `;)`